# VS code can verify but not run Dafny code

Tags: visual-studio-code, dafny

I am using the latest Dafny and VScode. But on a macOS 11.5  The Dafny code

```
function method Size(t: Tree): nat
decreases t
{
    match t
       case Leaf => 1
       case Node(l,r) => Size(l)+ Size(r)
}
        
method Main() {
  var tl:Tree := Leaf;
  var tc:Tree := Node(Node(Leaf, Leaf),Leaf);
  assert Size(tl) == 1;
  assert Size(tc) == 3;
  print "  ",Size(tl),"  ",Size(tc), "\n";
}
```

verifies but when I try to run it a popup tells me
*You don't have an extension for debugging Dafny. Should we find a Dafny extension in the Marketplace?*
but then can not find one in the marketplace.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Its getting worse. I tried downloading dafny and running it from the terminal. First MacOS complained that it could not trust the code. When I changed the settings to say I trusted it then it started but soon failed as it could not trust a dll tha dafny used. Does anyone know how to turn off macOS overly protectfull security?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to *run* (not debug) on Windows using Visual Studio Code after downloading the [Dafny extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=correctnessLab.dafny-vscode). Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile and run yielded the following in the terminal:

```
& "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.EXE" "c:\Users\timothy.granata\.vscode\extensions\correctnesslab.dafny-vscode-1.6.0\out\resources\dafny\Dafny.dll" "c:\Users\timothy.granata\Desktop\Untitled-1.dfy" /verifyAllModules /compile:3 /spillTargetCode:1 /o:1 /out:bin\Untitled-1

Dafny program verifier finished with 2 verified, 0 errors
Wrote textual form of target program to Untitled-1.cs
Running...

  1  3
```

Note that the extension does not have *debugging* support (only the ability to compile and *run* .dfy files), which is why you still receive the message about finding an Dafny extension that does (there does not appear to be any on the marketplace).  Simply choosing to run the code rather than debug it shouldn't result in this message appearing.

There are some other requirements for the extension as well, notably .NET Core 5.0, which should prompt you to install it manually if you do not have it:

> The plugin requires at least .NET Core 5.0 (the ASP.NET Core 5.0 runtime to be more specific) to run the Dafny Language Server. Please download a distribution from [Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). When you first open a Dafny file, the extension will prompt you to install .NET Core manually. The language server gets installed automatically.

As far as your issue goes with trusting the code, if it was Visual Studio Code that prompted you about this, that is because of a recently added feature known as [Workspace Trust](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust). As far macOS security issues, I am unsure as a non-Mac user.  Perhaps take a look [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491), towards the end of the page.

Comment: many thanks. But I have the dafny extension and I am selecting the "Run without Debugging" option from the Run list. Yet I still get the message that I don't have an extension for  debugging Dafny.   Not sure if this is a VScode issue of a dafny issue.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was also found by many students using MacOS, so is not to do with my installation. But, one of the  students had the solution.

On MacOS  the option to `Run without debugging` on the dropdown menu from `Run` does not work.  You need to right click on the file (control click) then take the `Dafny: Compile and Run` option. This then runs the file.