# VS code running dafny hangs when verifying on MacOS. Can I stop the verifier from VScode?

Tags: vscode-extensions, dafny

Running VS code with Dafny plugin but verifier hangs with

```
datatype List = Nil | Cons(head:nat, tail:List)
function sumNum(l:List) :nat
decreases l
{
    match l
       case Nil => 0
       case Cons(h,t) => h + sumNum(t)
}
method sumNumImp(l:List) returns (r:nat)
ensures r == sumNum(l)
{
    r := 0;
    var lin:List := l;
    while (lin.Cons?)
    // the next line will cause the verifier to hang! 
    decreases sumNum(l) - r
//With the following line program is verified
    //decreases lin
    invariant sumNum(l) == r + sumNum(lin)
    {
        r := r + lin.head;
        lin := lin.tail;
    }
}
```

My only solution is to edit the code and then kill Z3 from a terminal. Is there a better solution?

It may be that my installation is not working see
[VS code can verify but not run Dafny code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568110/vs-code-can-verify-but-not-run-dafny-code) but I have reinstalled half a dozen times.

Answer (score 0):

This is less an Answer and more conformation of the problem.
I am running Dafny in VScode on a macOS 11.5 (there appears to be nothing wrong with my installation in as much as the problem in `VS code can verify but not run Dafny code` is common on Student machines)

The following code causes Dafny to fall into a never ending cycle `Verifying`. The only solution I have found is to

1. uninstall Dafny
2. reload VScode and
3. reinstall Dafny.

```
datatype Option<T> = None | Some(e:T)
datatype Cash<K(==), V> =
    Empty|
    Bucket(key:K, history:seq<V>, rest:Cash<K,V>)

predicate method wFormed<K,V>(csh:Cash<K,V>, sofar:set<K>) 
{ csh.Empty?  }
predicate method dstrFormed<K,V>(csh:Cash<K,V>) {wFormed(csh, {})}

lemma wFormedAdd<K,V>( c:Cash<K,V> )
//ensures dstrFormed(c)
{ }
```

just uncomment the commented out ensures and wait for as long as you want.

I am teaching about 100 students so I really want to keep using VS code but things are getting worse.

While Zoom lecturing (covid) I sometimes have more than one zombie  Z3 processes running. Shutting down  VScode and killing the Z3 processes does not help as there must be another zombie process running that simply respawns replacement Z3 processes. The only solution I have found is to restart my computer. This is not a good look.  Does any one know the name of the dafny process that is responsible for Z3 spawning?
That way I might be able to save time and kill that process.

Answer (score 0):

The Dafny VS Code plugin has an option to disable automatic verification which should at least prevent it from hanging as soon as you open your code. Look for "Dafny: Automatic Verification" in the settings UI and set it to "never", or  add this to your settings.json: `"dafny.automaticVerification": "never"`.

This does mean you lose automatic verification, so you either have to use the terminal directly or the right click in the editor and select "Dafny: Compile". Either way you should then be able to force it to exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.